# Realm refresh() function no longer to existing

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I'm using `Realm Java`, I just updated to `version 0.91.1`, and I see that the function `realm.refresh()` doesn't exist any more. I guessed that an `auto refresh` takes place when I create a new `instance` of `Realm` but it does not. 
I see the function `setAutoRefresh(true)`, but I can't use it because it requires a looper thread.
So, can any one tell me what I should do to make sure that my `realm instance` points to the last update of `DB`?

Comment: In order to get Realms auto-updated, you have to be using Looper threads. On non-Looper threads, you can call [`waitForChange()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/1.0.1/api/io/realm/Realm.html#waitForChange--).

Comment: thank you @geisshirt but it did not help to me :(

Comment: sorry to hear that. Please post a code snippet which demonstrates the problem. For example, how do you see that your instance isn't updated?

Comment: Wait for change should do what you need.  If it doesn't, you can force the Realm to update with some package private methods, but it's not really recommended.